# Trying to iterate through a collection of MongoDb results to update another collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update some documents from DB-collection1 (source db) over to DB-collection2 (destination DB) .. all on the same MongoDb (with same permissions, etc).

**So for each document from DB-Collection1, update a specific document in DB-collectoin2, if it exists.**

The documents in DB-collection1 have following shape:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "commentId": "082f3de6-a268-46b5-803f-89bafd172621"
  },
  "appliesTo": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "documentId": "b1eb1ad5-e74c-4a64-a4f3-bdc67ba70b35"
        },
        "type": "Document"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the matching document in DB-collection2 is:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "documentId": "b1eb1ad5-e74c-4a64-a4f3-bdc67ba70b35"
  },
  "name": "jill"
},
```

I'm using a cursor to iterate through the source collection but I'm not sure how I can do this?

This is the <strike>javascript code</strike> mongo shell script I'm trying right now, when I run the following command on a machine where `mongo` is installed:

CLI: `root@f0cc2f13e70c:/src/scripts# mongo --host localhost --username root --password example copyFoosToBars.js`

```
// copyFoosToBars.js
function main() {

    print('Starting script.')
    print()

    var foosDb = db.getSiblingDB('foos');
    var barsDb = db.getSiblingDB('bars');

    // Grab all the 'foos' which have a some barId in some convoluted schema.
    var sourceFoos = foosDb.getCollection('foos')
        .find(
            {
                "appliesTo.targets.type" : "Document",
                "_meta.deleted": null
            }, 
            { 
                "_id" : 0,
                "appliesTo.targets._id.documentId" : 1
            }
        );

    sourceFoos.forEach(function(foo){

        // Check if this document exists in the bars-db
        var desinationBars = barsDb.getCollection('bars')
            .find(
                {
                    "_id.documentId" : foo.appliesTo.targets._id.documentId,
                }, 
            );

        printjson(desinationBars);

        // If destinationBars document exists, then add a the field 'Text' : 'hi there' to the document -or- update the existing field, if the 'Text' field already exists in this document.

    });


    print()
    print()
    print('----------------------------------------------')
}

main()
```

So here's some sample json output for the first part of the query -> which proves that I have some data which passes that 'find/search' clause:

```
Starting script.

{
        "appliesTo" : {
                "targets" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : {
                                        "barId" : "810e66e2-66d1-44f4-be0e-980309d8df8f"
                                }
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "appliesTo" : {
                "targets" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : {
                                        "barId" : "54f25223-67bb-4d5d-ad47-24392e4acbdf"
                                }
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "appliesTo" : {
                "targets" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : {
                                        "barId" : "34c83da3-eafd-41bf-93af-3a45d1644225"
                                }
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

This doesn't work.

```
MongoDB server version: 4.0.22
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
Starting script.

uncaught exception: TypeError: comment.appliesTo.targets._id is undefined :
main/
<snip>
```

Can someone please suggest some clues as to how I can fix this, please?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language is that?

Comment: i'm doing javascript, which i run with mongo command line. i'll update the topic with more info about this, for context

Comment: ah, that makes sense. The `print` confused me since it's the shell specific extension to the vanilla js. Could you add example documents from both collections (essential fields).

Comment: @AlexBlex how would you like me to add sample documents for both collections? as json snippets? like 2 or 3 documents per collection?

Comment: @AlexBlex https://mongoplayground.net/p/qv2JyqhZ5XL  I've changed the query to return some sample documents (a subset of the full 5 document-collection). Now i need to update the _other_ collection ... based on those 2 documents i returned in that sample data, i've setup.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question, including the queries to match structure of the documents. How do you expect it to work if there are 2 items in the `appliesTo.targets` array of the source document?

Comment: Great question! i don't know. I'm not 100% sure if there are 2+ items in the `appliesTo.targets` which have a `type == Document`. For arguments sake, lets assume that it's only 1 item for all returned source-documents.

Comment: Also, how large your dataset? The shell script is fine for small collections. It might not be robust enough for larger databases.

Comment: Fair enough, just keep in mind that a document that have at least one matching item in the array will pass the filter. Mohammad's answer is based on the assumption the first item in the array is the matching one and uses it for updates. If the matching item is the second one there will be no error but you will find unexpected updates in the DB-collection2.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to safeguard against multiple items in the appliesTo.targets.

A document

```
{
  "_id": {
    "commentId": "082f3de6-a268-46b5-803f-89bafd172621"
  },
  "appliesTo": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "documentId": "should-not-be-updated"
        },
        "type": "AnyOtherType"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "documentId": "b1eb1ad5-e74c-4a64-a4f3-bdc67ba70b35"
        },
        "type": "Document"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Will be selected by

```
    .find(
        {
            "appliesTo.targets.type" : "Document",
            "_meta.deleted": null
        }, 
        { 
            "_id" : 0,
            "appliesTo.targets._id.documentId" : 1
        }
    );
```

with the resulting document:

```
{
  "appliesTo": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "documentId": "should-not-be-updated"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "documentId": "b1eb1ad5-e74c-4a64-a4f3-bdc67ba70b35"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

so `foo.appliesTo.targets[0]._id.documentId` will be  "should-not-be-updated".

Structure of the document does not allow to use $elemMatch, so you have to either use aggregation framework or filter the array clientside. The aggregation has benefit of running serverside and reduce amount of data to transfer to the client.

Secondly, there is no point to `find` documents from DB-collection2. You can update all matching ones straight away, like in "update...where" SQL .

So the code must be something like following:

```
var sourceFoos = db.foos.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$appliesTo.targets"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "appliesTo.targets.type": "Document",
      "appliesTo.targets._id.documentId": {
        $exists: true
      },
      "_meta.deleted": null
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "documentId": "$appliesTo.targets._id.documentId"
    }
  }
]);

sourceFoos.forEach(function(foo){ 
    db.bars.updateMany(
        {"_id.documentId" : foo.documentId},
        {$set:{'Text' : 'hi there'}}
    )
})
```

If there are a lot of documents expected in the cursor I would recommend to look at [bulk updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) to speed it up, but as I mentioned earlier in this case mongo shell might not be an ideal tool.

Comment: thanks @alexblex ! i'll give this a go, today!

Answer (score 0):

`target` is an array so for accessing to the `_id` try like this :

```
foo.appliesTo.targets[0]._id.barId
```

use `async/await` with `try/catch` and use `.toArray()` after find query

```
// copyFoosToBars.js
async function main() {
  try {
    var foosDb = db.getSiblingDB("foos");
  var barsDb = db.getSiblingDB("bars");

  // Grab all the 'foos' which have a some barId in some convoluted schema.
  var sourceFoos = await foosDb
    .getCollection("foos")
    .find(
      {
        "appliesTo.targets.type": "Bar",
        "_meta.deleted": null,
      },
      {
        _id: 0,
        "appliesTo.targets._id.fooId": 1,
      }
    ).toArray();

  for (foo of sourceFoos) {
    var desinationBars = await barsDb
      .getCollection("bars")
      .find({
        "_id.barId": foo.appliesTo.targets[0]._id.barId,
      })
      .toArray();

    console.log(desinationBars);
    if(desinationBars.length> 0){
      //do somthings
    }
  }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  
}
```

in the first find query you select  `"appliesTo.targets._id.fooId" : 1`so select ( `fooId` but in the result json show `"barId" : "810e66e2-66d1-44f4-be0e-980309d8df8f"` it's conflict, Anyway, I hope this solution solves your problem

Comment: what happens .. if .. `_id.fooId` isn't the first item/slot in the array? (just in case the data isn't clean .. because I didn't create the data set)

Comment: whoa - crazy. fixing the code to using an `[ ]` returns all this ... javascript _code_ ! wtf?!

Comment: nope. it's made things worse. it's now dumping CODE (from mongo?) instead of db data.

Comment: can you explain what do you want exactly?

Comment: I would like to find out if the corresponding `bar` document exists, based upon the id returned in the `foos` collecton-result. So looking at the first result : `"barId" : "810e66e2-66d1-44f4-be0e-980309d8df8f"` .. does the `bar` document `810e66e2-66d1-44f4-be0e-980309d8df8f` exist? if yes, then update a single field. Now repeat this for every `foo` in the `foos` collection

Comment: the json is added to the question is result of console.log(sourceFoos )?

Comment: Yep - the json snippet is the data, all nice and pretty to display. It's the (correct) result from my `.find` query. So, give this result set .. i need to 1) iterate through it and for each result => 2) grab a document from the _other_ db-collection and then 3) update a field in that document, if the document exists.